# Puppeteer - domcontentloaded event firing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having trouble to understand how this event domcontentloaded is handled under puppeteer. I have the following snippet to demonstrate it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('load',()=> console.log('Loaded!',page.url()));
  page.on('domcontentloaded',()=>console.log('dom even fired'));
  await page.goto('https://cnn.com');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I don't see the **on domcontentloaded** is executed. I understand that this event should be fired for every webpage according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded.)

It is not executed because of syntax error or something I misunderstood for puppeteer?

Comment: Can you update snippet with an example how you start and close browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`page.on('domcontentloaded', callback)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-domcontentloaded) is only available in version 1.0.0-post. If you want to use it you should install newest (unstable) version:

```
npm install puppeteer@next
```

Comment: thanks, I read the latest doc but using older version of the lib.